# Usage of Found and Find

Tags: conditional-constructions

Which of the following sentences is correct?

1) If Found, Please return to

2) If Find, Please return to

Please give me reason too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, you can use the participles of a verb as adjectives. Using the past participle in such a way is very common:

> Marry -> participle *married* -> John is *married*, John is a married man.
>   Write -> participle *written* -> The book is *written*, it is a well-written book.
>   Forget -> participle *forgotten* -> The song is *forgotten*, it is a forgotten song.

In the same way, you have:

> Find -> particple *found* -> the key is *found*, it is a *found* key.

Your sentence is a shortened version of

> if (something is) found, please return (it) to...

The infinitive (find) is *not* used in this way, so your second sentence is not correct.

You *could*, as someasw mentions, rewrite the second version into something like *if you find it, please return it to...*.

Comment: Thank you, By the way, so we can use all past participles as adjectives in this way?

Comment: In principle, yes, you can, but in some cases the result may not be very well understood. You have to consider semantics (the meaning) of such phrases. _A trained dog_ makes more sense than _an understood dog_, even if I think I understand what the dog wants. There are probably verbs that can cause trouble, so don't assume this rule has no exceptions (like any "rule" in language!)

Answer (score 2):

You should use "If found, please return to..." here (I also corrected other typos).

"found" is needed because you need the passive form here: "If something is found, please return it to..."

2 is wrong the way you phrased it. Possible variation: "If you find it, return it to..."

Comment: i thought if i used "i found" that would be second conditional. Thanks for correcting me