# What verb form is in 'Page not found'?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, verb-forms

'Page not found' is popular web response phrase. What grammar behind such a use of verb 'find' is? For me it's expected to read 'Page is not found' or 'has not been'.

Comment: It's a shortened form that is also used in (newspaper) headlines, like _Minister killed in coup_. The verb _be_ is often left out in these shortened sentences, because people can understand the sentence even when it is left out. It's sometimes known as _headlinese_.

Comment: Thanks, haven't heard about that! Would you like to copy you comment to be marked as rightanswer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Usage of Found and Find](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98349/usage-of-found-and-find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shortened form that is also used in (newspaper) headlines, like *Minister killed in coup*. The verb be is often left out in these shortened sentences, because people can understand the sentence even when it is left out. It's sometimes known as headlinese.

Some examples from current [news.google](https://news.google.com/):

> [Police: Officers kill armed woman in apartment; **boy wounded**](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2016/08/02/police-officers-kill-armed-woman-apartment-boy-wounded/87945298/)
>
> [2 12-year-old **boys arrested** in teen's shooting death](https://www.washingtonpost.com/national/2-12-year-old-boys-arrested-in-teens-shooting-death/2016/08/02/017a3730-58a0-11e6-8b48-0cb344221131_story.html)

If you go through the headlines, you'll notice that other things are sometimes left out as well, to shorten the sentence. In paper newspapers, the space for headlines was limited, so editors became sometimes quite inventive in shortening them while still conveying the message.